# Tensorflow equivalent for Numpy indexed assignment

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

What is the pseudo(*)-equivalent in Tensorflow for this?

```
array[array < 50] = 0 # numpy
```

I guess it should be something like:

```
array = tf.something(array, ...) # or array2 = ...
# OR
array = array.something(...) # or array2 = ...
```

(*) I do not pretend to keep the array mutable neither it to be executed at the moment as I would be a tensor.

Maybe another way to ask this is: How would be the code for applying an array of conditional tensors of tf.cond() depending on tf.less() to an array of numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
tf.select(array < 50, tf.zeros_like(array), array)
```

which will return an expression equivalent to what `array` will contain after `array[array < 50] = 0`. If `array` was a TensorFlow variable, you can use [`tf.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#assign) to assign the above expression to `array`.

Comment: keveman's helping me with something right now, so I fixed it for him :).

Comment: Just wanted to mention that `tf.select` has been deprecated and removed in the recent release (I think 1.0 onwards). It's now `tf.where` (like the numpy equivalent `np.where`)