# Element-wise assignment in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

In `numpy`, it could be easily done as

```
>>> img
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)
>>> img[img>5] = [1,2,3,4]
>>> img
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 1],
       [2, 3, 4]], dtype=int32)
```

However, there seems not exist similar operation in tensorflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562576/tensorflow-equivalent-for-numpy-indexed-assignment ?

Comment: `tf.select` is replace by `tf.where`. Moreover, here I would like to assign random values but not just from the original array or `0`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never assign a value to a tensor in tensorflow as the change in tensor value is not traceable by backpropagation, but you can still get another tensor from origin tensor, here is a solution

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
img = tf.constant(list(range(1, 10)), shape=[3, 3])
replace_mask = img > 5
keep_mask = tf.logical_not(replace_mask)
keep = tf.boolean_mask(img, keep_mask)

keep_index = tf.where(keep_mask)
replace_index = tf.where(replace_mask)

replace = tf.random_uniform((tf.shape(replace_index)[0],), 0, 10, tf.int32)

updates = tf.concat([keep, replace], axis=0)
indices = tf.concat([keep_index, replace_index], axis=0)

result = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(indices, tf.int32), updates, shape=tf.shape(img))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to achieve this. Very similar to @Jie.Zhou's answer, you can replace `tf.constant` with `tf.Variable`, then replace `tf.scatter_nd` with `tf.scatter_nd_update`