# Item assignment in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to convert the following code in Numpy to Tensorflow, so that I can use that code in my neural network. Sadly, I have failed to so yet, due to the error, that Tensorflow does not support item assignment, which I would need for this code to work.

```py
# Create zeros matrices
l_bbox = np.zeros((6,6), np.float32)
l_score = np.zeros((1,6,6), np.float32)
# Set coordinates
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 1, 1, 5, 4
# Assign coordinates to the zeros matrix
l_score[:, y1:y2, x1:x2] = 1.
l_score
"""
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
"""
# Assign varying values to l_bbox
for yy in range(y1, y2):
    l_bbox[yy, x1:x2] = yy - y1
l_bbox
"""
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 2., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
"""
```

I have tried to do this first in a loop and then stack the lists up using `tf.stack`, but that seems like a really non-tensorflow way (and it does not work on a GPU). What I would like to have is a way to do the aforementioned transformation for several batch sizes in Tensorflow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718305/element-wise-assignment-in-tensorflow) answer suggests to use `tf.where` but I also have no clue how to leverage this in that specific case. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think the function you are looking for is [tf.scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update). It allows you to update specific positions in your tensor based on an index tensor. The usage of this function can be a bit tricky, I would suggest to read the corresponding documentation and experiment with the function to understand how to formulate `indices` and `updates` to make it work in your situation. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice and directly assign like this assuming the logic you have is simple as shown. But there are also other functions to do this.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tfl_bbox = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([6, 6]))
tfl_score = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 6, 6]))
# Set coordinates
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 1, 1, 5, 4
# Assign coordinates to the zeros matrix
tfl_score[:, y1:y2, x1:x2].assign(tf.ones_like(tf.constant(1,shape=(1,y2-y1,x2-x1)), dtype=tf.float32))

# Create zeros matrices
l_bbox = np.zeros((6,6), np.float32)
l_score = np.zeros((1,6,6), np.float32)
# Set coordinates
x1, y1, x2, y2 = 1, 1, 5, 4
# Assign coordinates to the zeros matrix
l_score[:, y1:y2, x1:x2] = 1.
print(l_score)
print(tfl_score)
"""
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
"""
# Assign varying values to l_bbox
for yy in range(y1, y2):
    l_bbox[yy, x1:x2] = yy - y1
    tfl_bbox[yy, x1:x2].assign(tf.constant(yy - y1,shape=(x2-x1), dtype=tf.float32))
print(l_bbox)
print(tfl_bbox)
"""
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 2., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
"""
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohan, that is really insightful! Do you also have an idea how to do this, if the coordinates are themselves tensors, e.g. `x1 = tf.constant([1,2]), ...`? Because then the slicing idea does not work anymore.